# Small question about a proof of Hilbert's Basis Theorem

Tags: commutative-algebra, polynomials

I am currently going going through the proof of Hilbert's Basis Theorem:
http://www.maths.usyd.edu.au/u/de/AGR/CommutativeAlgebra/pp806-850.pdf 
(it starts on slide 832)

On slide 836-837 he makes the following statement:

> Put $q(x) = p(x) −\sum_{i=1}^n u_i x^{m-d_i}p_i(x)$.
>   Then $q(x)$ is an element of $J$ of degree $<m$. By an inductive hypothesis,
>   $q(x) \in (J \cap M) + J'$.

I understand that by subtracting $\sum_{i=1}^n u_i x^{m-d_i}p_i(x)$ he erases the leading coefficient of $p(x)$ and hence $q(x)$ has degree less than $m$. But what I don't understand is how the inductive step works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, I would prefer to say "iterating this argument", or something similar, instead of "by an inductive hypothesis".

You started off with a polynomial $p(x)\in J$ of degree $m>d$, and you found a way to write it as $p(x)=q(x)+q'(x)$, where $q'(x)$ is in $J'$. Since $q(x)$ itself is in $J$, you can repeat the same argument and write it as $q(x)=r(x)+r'(x)$, and so on.
Note that at every iteration you are working with a polynomial of degree strictly less then the degree of the one you started with. Therefore it will take only a finite amount of steps to get an element of $J\cap M$, so you can write $p(x)$ as a sum of something in $J\cap M$ and something in $J'$, which is your claim.

Comment: So $q(x)=r(x)+r'(x)$ with $r'(x)\in J'$ and $r(x)\in J$ with $\deg r(x) < \deg q(x)$. And ultimately, after $n$ iterations, we get $p(x)= r_n(x)+ r_{n-1}'+\ldots+ r_1'(x) +r'(x)+q'(x)$ for some polynomials $r_i'(x)\in J'$ and $\deg r(x)\le d$, i.e. $p(x)\in (J\cap M)+J'$ ?

Comment: Exactly, @Thomas.